# WPF Entity Невозможно добавить запись в таблицу

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity

> Необработанное исключение типа
>   "System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException" в
>   EntityFramework.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: При обновлении записей возникла ошибка.
>   Дополнительные сведения приведены во внутреннем исключении.

Может дело в самой бд? Как посмотреть внутренние исключения?

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;


namespace EntityLast
{

public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    StudentsandGroupEntities db;
    Student item;

    public Window2()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Window2(StudentsandGroupEntities db)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Title = "Добавление";
        this.db = db;
    }

    public Window2(Student item, StudentsandGroupEntities db)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        db = new StudentsandGroupEntities();
        var l = db.Students.ToList();

        this.DataContext = l;
        this.comboBox.ItemsSource = db.Groups.ToList();

        Title = "Редактирование";
        this.item = item;
        this.db = db;
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.Text = item?.IDStudent.ToString();
        textBox1.Text = item?.Surname.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = item?.Name.ToString();
        textBox3.Text = item?.AddName.ToString();
        LoadComboBoxData();
    }


    public void LoadComboBoxData()
    {
        comboBox.ItemsSource = db.Groups.ToList();
        comboBox.SelectedValue = item != null ? item.IDGroup : 0;
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            if (item != null)//редактирует
            {
                var row = db.Students.Where(s => s.IDStudent == item.IDStudent).FirstOrDefault();
                // row.IDStudent = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text);
                row.Surname = textBox1.Text;
                row.Name = textBox2.Text;
                row.AddName = textBox3.Text;
                row.IDGroup = int.Parse(comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else
            {
                var row = new Student()//добавляет
                {
                    // IDStudent = Convert.ToInt32(textBox.Text),
                    Surname = textBox1.Text,
                    Name = textBox2.Text,
                    AddName = textBox3.Text,
                    IDGroup = int.Parse(comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString())
                };
                db.Students.Add(row);
                db.SaveChanges();//ошибка здесь

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Дело оказалось действительно в самой бд, надо заполнять все поля в базе, которые NOT NULL, либо все менять на NULL, кроме айдишника

Comment: Продебажьте значение `row` на строке `db.Students.Add(row);`. Подозреваю, что `IDGroup` - pk, которому сетается `-1`. Либо `IDStudent` не автоинкрементный айдишник в базе...

Comment: @AGS17 IDStudent автоинкрементный, и IDGroup получает выбранное значение в комбобоксе. Исключение такое: {"Невозможно вставить явное значение для столбца идентификаторов в таблице \"Students\", когда параметр IDENTITY_INSERT имеет значение OFF."}

Comment: А `IDStudent` помечен как `Key` и `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)`?

Comment: @AGS17 не помечен был, сделал так, но все равно то же исключение выскакивает